# Create Athena Workgroups using template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

Here is a nice blog post explaining how to configure two workgroups for Athena. One for ad hoc users and another for automated reports.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/separating-queries-and-managing-costs-using-amazon-athena-workgroups/

Is there a cloudformation template to automate all the steps mentioned?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/90

Comment: Thanks for that link @PatMyron I have one more question. I am aware that SFTP supports cloudformation. But can someone point me to an example template file?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Transfer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of your question, Athena Workgroups creation using AWS CloudFormation was not supported. Recently, Amazon Athena added support for managing Athena Workgroups using AWS CloudFormation (03/13/2020). You can use **AWS::Athena::WorkGroup** to create Athena Workgroups.

More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-workgroup.html